# Can't connect excel/vba to SQL Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, excel, vba, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to connect an excel/vba (office 2010) macro to remote SQL Oracle 11g database.

I installed the Oracle `OraDb11g_home1` client.

The DB Administrator provided me the following parameters:

- user: `user205`
- password: `password205`
- connectstring: `(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=128.128.128.20)(PORT=1527)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=gestores)))`

My tries:

1)

```
Sub GetData()
    Dim SQL_String As String
    Dim dbConnectStr As String
    Set con = New ADODB.Connection
    Set recset = New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim recordCount As Long
    dbConnectStr = "Provider=msdaora;Data Source=" & "gestores; User Id=user205" & "; Password=" & "password205"
    con.ConnectionString = dbConnectStr
    'con.Properties("Prompt") = adPromptAlways
    con.Open dbConnectStr 'ConnectionString
    MsgBox "Connected!!"
    SQL_String = "select * from USER_TABLES"
    recset.Open SQL_String, con
    recset.MoveLast
    recordCount = recset.recordCount
    recset.MoveFirst
    Do While Not recset.EOF = True
         'Have a loop here to go through all the fields
        recset.MoveNext
    Loop
    recset.Close
End Sub
```

This one thows me this message: `ORA-12154:TNS: could not resolve the connect identifier specified`

2)

```
Sub OracleConnect()
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset, c As New ADODB.Connection, r As Range
    c.ConnectionString = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=128.128.128.20)(PORT=1527)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=gestores))) ;UID=user205;PWD=password205;"
    c.Open
    rs.Open "select * from USER_TABLES", c, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Test")
    Set r = ws.Range("A1")
    r.CopyFromRecordset rs
    rs.Close
    c.Close
End Sub
```

This one thows me this message: `[Microsoft][OCDB Driver for Oracle][Oracle]ORA-12541:TNS: No listener`

Comment: For the second attempt, are you sure the address and particularly the port number are right? Did you get those from your DBA, and have you tried connecting from other clients?

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes, they are right.  I'm using they with PL/SQL Developer client from _Allround Automations_